# How to install macports openmpi on Mac osx 10.5.8?

Tags: macos, build, macports, mpi

I want the latest version of openmpi. I like to use macports because it is easy to install, uninstall, and upgrade software. I have installed the latest mpi via building from source, but no one seems to be able to get it to build properly with macports. There is always a build error. There are tickets (and you can see the logs at ), but they seem to be collecting dust and it seems strange that no one had found a solution.

I have tried uninstalling the built in version (I know, openmpi says not to do that--but it works fine if I reinstall it--even in a different directory), but I still the same build errors. I also tried with different gcc.

Does anyone know what is so difficult about getting openmpi via macports?

Comment: Isn't this question better asked on superuser.com?

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to the macports bug reports?

I build local installations of Open MPI all the time on my Macbook Pro (Snow Leopard, and previously with Leopard).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo port install openmpi
```

worked for me

Comment: That is exactly what did not work for me. Since it failed to build despite reinstalling xcode, macports, and a fresh installation of leapord (different reason) it still did not work, I assumed it had to be a universal error.